# How can get the user information which is logged in

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, passport.js

I create a foreign key for my employee table, but i am facing the issue to fetch the specific user information  it just only show the first record of employee table.i want to get only that user information which is logged in. but it not show the information of that user, which is logged in.

Employee Model:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const Schema = mongoose.Schema

let EmployeeSchema = new Schema({

user_Id:{

    type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectID,

    ref:'User'

},

Contact_No:{

    type : Number,

    unique : true,

    required : true
},

Address:{

    type : String,

    required : true

},


})

Employee = mongoose.model('Employee', EmployeeSchema)

module.exports = Employee
```

Login.js

```
router.post('/login', function (req, res, next) {

passport.authenticate("local" , function (err, user, info) {

if(err) {

  return next(err)

}

if(!user){

  return res.redirect('/login')

}

req.logIn(user, function (err) {

  if(err){ return next(err)}

  req.session.isLoggedIn = true

  req.session.user = user

  req.session.save(err=>{

    console.log(err)

    if(req.isAuthenticated()){

      console.log()

      return res.redirect('/menu')

    }else{

      console.log('user not exist')

      return  res.redirect('/')
    }
  })

})
})(req, res, next)
```

})

EmployeeInfo.js

```
const express = require('express')

const router = express.Router()

const User = require('../model/auth_user')

const Employee = require('../model/employee')


router.get('/employee_info', function (req, res ) {

console.log(req.params.id)

Employee.findOne({userId:req.param.id}, function (err, employee) {

    if(err){

        console.log(err);

    }

    else {

        console.log(employee)

        res.render('employeeinfo',{employee:employee})

    }
}) 
})

module.exports = router
```

Employee.Ejs

```
<title> Sign Up </title>

<link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/style.css' />
```

```
<tbody>

<tr>

    <td>id</td>

    <td>Contact_No: </td>

    <td>Address: </td>

</tr>

<tr>

    <td><%= employee._id%></td>

    <td><%= employee.Contact_No%></td>

    <td><%= employee.Address%></td>

</tr>


</tbody>

</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: but it just only show the first record of employee table, what does it mean?

Comment: it mean there is a lot of employe's record data  but i just only show the first record of employee table .

Comment: if i understood you correctly when the user gets login you need to set the user data to the session and then you pass it to your ejs page

Comment: . your question is a bit complicated to understand, can you make it little more clearly what you want to do

Comment: @usmanimtiaz It shows the first record because you use `.findOne()` to get only *one* employee and pass that to the ejs page. If you need multiple employees you'll have to query multiple employees and the ejs page should handle multiple employees as well

Comment: i just want to get only that user information which is logged in

Comment: i simplify the question , now u can understand better what i want.

Comment: i just want to get only that user information which is logged in